Annotating each point on the graph on a loop with matplotlib
I am trying to annotate each point the graphs on the loop with the country but can not figure out how to di it in a loop.
Here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('edff.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
         
    writer.writerow(["Name", "2000", "2001", "2002"])
    writer.writerow(["Afg", "500", "529","531"])
    writer.writerow(["Alb", "125", "127","129"])
    writer.writerow(["Alg", "52", "54", "55"])
    
with open('cdff.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
         
    writer.writerow(["Name", "2000", "2001", "2002"])
    writer.writerow(["Afg", "501", "531","532"])
    writer.writerow(["Alb", "124", "126","130"])
    writer.writerow(["Alg", "50", "52", "55"])
    
edff=pd.read_csv("edff.csv")
cdff=pd.read_csv("cdff.csv")
    
years = edff.columns.tolist()
years.pop(0)
years = [int(ystr) for ystr in years]
n=1
for year in years:
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
    plt.scatter(edff[str(year)], cdff[str(year)], alpha=0.5)
        
    #Getting the country associated with the dot
    for i in range(len(edff)):
        name = edff.iloc[i, 0] 
        plt.text(edff.iloc[i, year - 2000-n], cdff.iloc[i, year - 2000-n], name, fontsize=10)
        plt.plot( [0,600],[0,600] )
    
    n += 1

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

The result should look similar to this: 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def annot_max(x,y, ax=None):
    ymax = y[np.argmax(x)]
    xmax = x.max()
    y_pos = np.argmax(x)/len(y)
    
    text= f"{ymax}"
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    ax.plot([xmax], [ymax], 'o')
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
              verticalalignment="center", horizontalalignment="left",
              arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.01))
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(0.5, y_pos), **kw)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(4,7):
    y = np.linspace(-2,8, num=301)
    x = np.sinc(y-i)*i
    ax.plot(x,y, label = f"{i}")
    annot_max(x,y)

plt.legend()    
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()

Output:


Thank you, but maybe I was not clear.  I meant the arrow pointing the dot should be like the example provided not the whole graph and applied to my code above.

It is just a simple example how you can annotate the maximum value.
Otherwise I would recommend to check this topic to find more examples with annotations.
